# Удалить элемент из списка, если он длиннее 4

Tags: python

Нужен код, чтобы удалить из списка элемент, если он длиннее 4х. Вот что у меня вышло, не работает, конечно же.

```
def friend(x):
    for i in x:
        if len(i) > 4:
            return x.remove(i)

print(friend(["Ryan", "Kieran", "Mark"]))
```

Comment: почему " конечно же"?

Comment: да только начал вникать

Comment: Ну, хорошо, что стараетесь. Ответил ниже. На будущее: лучше писать просто "не работает", а то непонятно + Приводите конкретные тестовые примеры, пожалуйста. Что на входе, что ожидается на выходе, что на самом деле на выходе. Полный (все строки) текст ошибки, если есть, и указание на строку к которой она выдана. Тогда выше шанс получить помощь.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

У вас классическая ошибка, так как нельзя изменять список в процессе итерирования по нему (это когда `for i in x:`).
Лучше создавать новый, как в примере внизу.
Кроме того, вы зря выходите из функции сразу по обнаружении первого длинного элемента, а вдруг там их таких больше? (исправлено тоже)

```
def friend(x):
    ret = []
    for i in x:
        if len(i) <= 4:
            ret.append(i)
    return ret

print(friend(["Ryan", "Kieran", "Mark"]))
```

Answer (score 3):

Можно так:

```py
a = ["Ryan", "Kieran", "Mark"]
*res, = filter(lambda x: len(x) <= 4, a)
print(res) # ['Ryan', 'Mark']
```

Но это создает новый список.
Если задача именно удалить элемент из имеющегося списка, то можно попробывать так:

```py
def friend(x):
    for i in range(len(x)-1, -1, -1):
        if len(x[i]) > 4:
            x.pop(i)

a = ["Ryan", "Kieran", "Mark"]
friend(a)
print(a) # ['Ryan', 'Mark']
```

Comment: Ответ, отметил, конечно, за сложность, но вот только для человека с "да только начал вникать" это будет весело:-)

Comment: @Сергей, спасибо. Если человек действительно хочет вникать, то пойдет дальше и вникнет - потому, что это весело :-)